# Javassist : How do I call a nondefault constructor on a dynamically generated class?

Tags: java, reflection, assembly, code-generation, javassist

I have put a lot of time into this problem and to no avail.  Ideally I would like to pass a parameter into the constructor of a dynamically generated class.  The problem is that I don't know how to instantiate with a parameterized constructor.

My approach to instantiation so far has been ...

```
CtClass myClass . . . 
myClass.addInterfaces(.... //assume I have an interface that is nondynamic
InterfaceName interfaceinstance = (InterfaceName) (myClass.toClass().newInstance());
```

Is there a better way to go about this that will provide more flexibility?

Thank you so much!

RB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assume you want to invoke constructor, which takes a string as param (I suppose you know the signature)

```
Class clazz = object.getClass();
Constructor ctr = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class);
Object instance = ctr.newInstance("Foo");
```

Comment: Fantastic.  Here I was wasting my time looking in the Javassist API.  Reflection is a crazy thing, thanks for your help!